# How can I delete Safari cookies via Terminal on 10.7.2?

Tags: safari, macos

I would like to delete all Safari cookies from terminal on Mac OS 10.7.2.

I tried to delete `~/Library/Cookie/Cookies.binarycookies` (this is the only file in `~/Library/Cookie`), but it didn't help.

Please advise.

Comment: I have a file `Cookies.plist` in `~/Library/Cookies`, which I think is what stores them. Do you have any other files in there?

Answer (score 1):

The missing part was to kill the `cookied` process:

```
killall cookied
```